# pyarmor obfuscation on Mac (arwin.aarch64)

Tags: python, obfuscation, pyarmor

I'm trying to obfuscate a script using pyarmor (bought license) but I'm getting the following error:

`is incompatible with target arch arm64 (has arch: x86_64)!`

I've read the docs and I've found this part where it shows the default supported platforms that already come with pyarmor + the other dynamic libraries that pyarmor downloads the first time it runs:

https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms.html#support-platforms

I've checked my directory at `~/.pyarmor/platforms/SYSTEM/ARCH/N/` as it's indicated on the docs and I can find a folder named darwin with the corresponding arch. As far as I can understand my system it's compatible with pyarmor, but I'm probably missing some extra steps before the obfuscation as the system version it's not on pyarmor by default.

This is the command im currently executing:

`pyarmor pack -e" --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon icon.ico --add-data contract.py:. --add-data launchpad.py:. --add-data utils.py:. --add-data neuradb.py:." Neura.py`

It wored just fine on my Windows 10 but having some trouble on Mac, if anyone could help me I would appreciate it as it's an important project and I have to release it soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the  `--platform linux.x86_64` setting on obfuscate command. There is also one for mac.

Check here for the docs:https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms.html?highlight=platform#standard-platform-names

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in here.

https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor/issues/568.

Basically you need to run `rm -rf  ~/.pyarmor/platforms` and then `export PYARMOR_PLATFORM=darwin.aarch64.0` before you run pyarmor obfuscate

Comment: If you want to use advanced mode, you will need to buy the pro version.